# Geocomplete jQuery plugin: initialize page to browser location

Tags: google-maps, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to get the 'example/form.html' page to initialize in the browser with the browser's current location. To no avail. With this I was trying to pass in a variable of the browser's current location using jQuery. I have also tried to set the location variable in jquery.geocomplete.js manually, using an array, also to no avail. I was trying this:

var defaults = {
    bounds: true,
    country: null,
    map: false,
    details: false,
    detailsAttribute: "name",
    location: ['-27.470933,153.023502'],

I have also tried `location: ['-27.470933','153.023502']`.

My understanding is that 'bounds' should be set as a meter radius so I will probably also fill that with 5000 if the initial will load. I have also tried pulling in using:

```
position.coords.latitude
position.coords.longitude;
```

Any direction on where I should be looking will be appreciated. Another alternative could be just to use the Google AutoComplete though I have been having the same problem.

Comment: Getting the browser's long/lat is asynchronous. Have you taken this into account?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to pull off with JQuery Geocomplete.
But to access your HTML5 latitude and longitude position, here's some script:

```
function init() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(browser_geolocation_success, browser_geolocation_error);
  }
}

function browser_geolocation_success(geolocation) {
  // now here you access your html5 latitude and longitude
  // by requesting -> geolocation.coords.latitude ;and -> geolocation.coords.longitude
}
```

In the last function above, you can do stuff with your position, like create a marker on a Google Maps thats loaded within your HTML already.